# Is there a postgres database extension for zip to state data?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We have a large set of addresses. Some of them are entered incorrectly with mismatched zip to state (for example zip code 10314 should be NY, but our data says its AL). I am trying to fix this. Is there an extension that we can use in Postgres(9.5) for this purpose? I am basically looking for zip codes in US and their corresponding states. I have just started looking into Postgis. Does postgis offer the functionality I am looking for? Any recommendations?

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need an extension, couldn't you just download [a spreadsheet](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv), [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) it to a table, and write a simple `UPDATE`?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but didn't know if there is a more elegant way of doing this.